# Infinity values in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, nan

When GNU compiler prints `inf` on infinite values, can I change that to a different output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
{
   float runs = 40.0;
   float wickets = 0.0;

   printf("Average = %.2f(/*This is the place where I want to print NA 
   instead of inf*/)", runs / wickets);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write your own function for printing..

Comment: FYI, you don't need `<math.h>` for this, since you're not calling any of the floating-point functions declared in that header. The `/` division operator is built into the language and doesn't need to be declared. (But you will need `<math.h>` if you add a call to `isinf()`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change how an infinity value is printed.  But you can check for it and act accordingly.

```
double avg = runs / wickets;
if (isinf(avg)) {
    printf("Average = NA\n");
} else {
    printf("Average = %.2f\n", avg);
}
```

Comment: But this isinf macro isn't working properly when I use it for fprintf. I can't figure out the errror : (  @dbush

Comment: "Isn't working properly" doesn't mean anything.  *How* is it not working?  Show some code with your attempt, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @shehan_sr: Since you've accepted the answer, I presume you figured out the problem, whatever it was.

Comment: @KeithThompson There was a deleted comment where OP said he was missing an `else` that fixed things.